# JSON.parse boolean type

Tags: javascript, jquery

послылаю с бекенда(.net) объект user с полем boolean IsActive
в js принимаю

```
init: function (data){
if (data != null) {
                UserHelper.fillFields(JSON.parse(data), dataAdapter.records);
            }
}
```

иннициализирую поля на UI форме

```
        fillFields: function (data, ddlSource) {
 if (data == null) {              
                $("#isActive").prop('checked', true);

                return;
            }

            var isTrue = (data.IsActive == 'true');
            $("#isActive").prop('checked', isTrue);
}
```

Все поля заполняются как надо кроме checkbox. Пробовал и как выше и просто `$("#isActive").prop('checked', data.IsActive);` не работает. в c# поле имеет тип boolean. в каком виде js парсит его?

попробовал для интереса             `$("#isActive").prop('checked', true);` тоже не работает. как задавать чекбоксу состояние?

Comment: дак посмотрите в отладчике то или в консоль выведите, в чем проьблема-то?

Comment: Взял для себя за правило передавать и получать boolean в json как 0-1, больше таких проблем не испытываю. `$("#isActive").prop('checked',(data.IsActive==1))`

Comment: объект как надо. А вот в js я не понимаю ничего, как его отлаживать? чем?

Comment: Инструменты разработчика(пкм по странице - `просмотреть код элемента` для хромиумных браузеров)

Comment: Посмотрел в функцию приходит "IsActive":true
даже $("#isActive").prop('checked', true); не работает почему то(проверяю на хроме)

Comment: $('#isActive').jqxCheckBox({ checked:true }); заработало вот это

Answer (score 0):

дело не в парсинге, а в js функции

```
$('#isActive').jqxCheckBox({ checked: data.IsActive });
```

заработала данная конструкция(браузер Хром)

Answer (score 0):

Так как в C# поле имело тип boolean, то и в сериализованном виде это поле так же было бы типом boolean.

В примере в вопросе, в строке

```
data.IsActive == 'true'
```

Происходит сравнение boolean и строки

```js
console.log(false == 'true')
console.log(true == 'true')
```

Как можно убедиться, результат всегда `false`.

Вместо этого можно сравнивать без кавычек

```
data.IsActive == true
```

Либо использовать сразу `data.IsActive` в нужном месте.